# How can I & how do I change text displayed in comment via child theme

Tags: customization, themes, comments, child-theme

This isn't a specific theme I'm asking for, well, yes it is, but I assume the answer would work on any theme..

I've recently learned little about child theme, but I'm not understanding how to change stuff. For example, the following code (see screenshot)

[image: Code]

This is the main themes comments.php, and as I've leavene learned, you shouldn't change the themes code, and instead modify the child theme.

But how? If I for example wants to change the marked text to: One idea, idea & ideas, I would normally just change it, but not when you're using child theme.

So what do I do? 
Copy the php snippet and create a new comments.php in my child theme directory?
Should I MOVE the code from the mother theme to the child?
.. Or is it more complicated than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should copy comments.php in the child theme and then make the changes there.

NOTE: DO NOT DELETE THE FILE FROM THE PARENT THEME.

You can read more about parent and child theme here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Answer (score 1):

Child themes work by copying just the file(s) you want to modify into the child theme folder. So the original should still exist in the parent theme, and you have a copy in the child theme which you then modify. The only other requirement for a child theme is that you must have a `style.css` file with at least a couple of comments, so that you identify the parent theme and WP knows to use the child theme in unison with the parent.